# Setting LayoutParams doesn't get applied quick enough

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

I currently have this UI structure:

```
Activity (ACT)
  LinearLayout (LL)
    HorizontalScrollView (HSV)
      RelativeLayout (RL)
```

When I set the layout parameters of RL, they don't get applied until later, when it is too late.

```
var TotalWidth = GetNewWidth() // eg returns 1000...

var lp = this.LayoutRoot.LayoutParameters;
lp.Width = TotalWidth;
this.LayoutRoot.LayoutParameters = lp;

// this.LayoutRoot.LayoutParameters.Width == 1000
// this.LayoutRoot.Width == 0

this.LayoutRoot.RequestLayout();
this.LayoutRoot.ForceLayout();
this.RequestLayout();    
this.ForceLayout();

// this.LayoutRoot.LayoutParameters.Width == 1000
// this.LayoutRoot.Width == 0
```

This is not a problem if I wasn't using the width, but I am :)
I want to do this:

```
this.ScrollTo(500, 0);
```

This has no effect as the total width of the HSV children is currently 0.

But, if I do this:

```
this.PostDelayed(() => this.ScrollTo((int) percent, 0), 500);
```

It works, after a 500ms delay.

The HSV is a derived class that manages its contents itself - just an empty RL that I use to set the width so that I can have a huge area for painting images. Sort of an massive scrolling canvas.
Also, what I am trying to do is in the HSV's OnSizeChanged overridden member. I want to make it so that if the control is re-sized, the control is scrolled to the same position. The width is dependent on the height (keeps aspect ratio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to wait till your layout has been recalculated. When you call `forceLayout` layouting doesn't happen immediately, it just gets added to the queue in the UI thread. `onLayout` or `onSizeChanged` will be called for all involved views as soon as they get their new positions and sizes assigned. Nothing really you can do about that.